# CompactRIO : Sends data over wifi ( TCP )

Tags: tcp, labview

I am a beginner in Labview, developing an application to send data retrieved by an acquisition model (CRIO) to my PC via wifi. I used the TCP protocol, as indicated in the attached program. I have an application on my PC listening to the traffic being sent and received. Unfortunately, it is not receiving any data.

http://we.tl/8WZeeqehdr

Comment: Please include the code you're trying, along with your expected result. Note your link is not very informative.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a TCP listener. You do not have to specify the IP address, as the listener will use the network resources to listen. When the listener is up and running use your socket test to connect to it.

Please see the changes to your code ( I carved out the timed loop etc .. as I needed to run this on the my PC to test )

[image: Example]